# Break line even if it fits the screen

Tags: wrapping, quickfix

I think everyone knows that vim can't display multiline messages in quickfix (yes, I know that it can parse them and show them as one big line).
I thought about ways to workaround this and thought what if vim can wrap lines at arbitrary characters, I know it can wrap lines that are longer than number current screen. Maybe it can be done with arbitrary lines?
If it would be so I could insert some characters instead of newlines in multiline messages so that vim would break lines at this characters.

Answer (score 1):

The `linebreak` option instructs vim to wrap at the characters specified in the `breakat` option (by default spaces and a handful of punctuation characters).  You can choose some "harmless" control character.  For example, ^Y or control+Y

```
set wrap linebreak
exe "set breakat=\<c-y>"
```

will turn

```
I think everyone knows that vim can't display^Ymultiline messages in quickfix
```

(visually) into

```
I think everyone knows that vim can't display^Y
multiline messages in quickfix
```

This introduces the problem that `<c-y>` is visible as `^Y`.  For this you could use vim's conceal feature.

```
syn match QFBreak /\%o31/ conceal cchar=↲
set cole=2
```

To completely hide the character, use `set cole=3` instead.

Comment: This will only break if the line isn't fitted on the screen. I'm talking about breaking it even if it fits the screen.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I don't know personally, but hopefully someone else has a solution.

Comment: I don't have high hopes on that. Since this would be a nice workaround for multiline quickfix problem and I never heard of it.